# Переполнение при делении

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, (желательно пример на С++), каким образом происходит переполнение стэка (буфера) при выполнении операции деления? В рунете нашел похожую тему, но на Assembler, а я в нем ни в зуб ногой.

Comment: Так стека или буфера?

Comment: Может, стоило дать ссылку на ту самую похожую тему на Assembler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, если вы очень большое число делите на очень маленькое (`1e200 / 1e-200`), это это всё равно что перемножить два больших числа. Вот вам и переполнение.

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены, что речь о переполнении стека/буфера?

Может, все же [арифметика (в частности, деление на ноль)](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/int_0000.php).

Comment: по поводу стэка  или буфера не уверен. Препод говорил просто переполнение при делении

Comment: @Роман Пономаренко, если речь о переполнении стека при выполнении операции деления (впервые слышу), то не сочтите за труд, когда разузнаете хоть какие-то подробности -- черкните тут пару строк.

Comment: @avp я так понял, переполнение переменной. Т.е если int delta = 21 2 147 483 647 + 1 - произойдет переполнение.

Comment: Это арифметика. См. ссылку в ответе.